# arithmetic sum of function parameters

Tags: c++, c++14

please comment the code what is wrong in my implementation of this  known task

```
template <typename T>
T arithmetic_sum(T first) {
    return first;
}

template<typename T, typename... Types>
auto arithmetic_sum(T first, Types ...others) ->decltype(first + arithmetic_sum(others...)) {
    return first + arithmetic_sum(others...);
}
```

(GCC 4.9)

e.g. this call

```
auto i = arithmetic_sum(123, 123.45, 0.55l);
```

can't be compiled with error:

error: no matching function for call to 'arithmetic_sum(int, double, long double)'

auto i = arithmetic_sum(123, 123.45, 0.55l);
                                                            ^

Comment: Btw, in C++14 you can just get rid of the `->decltype(...)`. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/47bd3cf7dd892766